# why is it showing error . Like I thought the third loop will end and it will enter the first loop but didn't else showed an exception

Tags: java, string, for-loop, nested-loops

I don't get why it is showing [that exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxRXv.jpgpackage) when looping:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 26 out of bounds for length 26 at
> loops.SuggestingAppNames.main(SuggestingAppNames.java:29)

I wanted to have all the possible arrangements of the English alphabet.

```
public class SuggestingAppNames {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("the possible outcomes are");

    String a = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
    String d[] = a.split(",");

    String b = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
    String e[] = b.split(",");

    String c = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
    String f[] = c.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {

      for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++) {

        for (int k = 0; k < c.length(); k++) {

          System.out.println(d[i] + e[j] + f[k]);

        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: The number of elements in the arrays is less than the length of strings because the delimiters won't put in the arrays.

Comment: It also doesn't show just "an error", but _a specific error_ you should share.

Comment: If it showed an exception, please paste the exception and complete stack trace as text. Don't handicap the volunteers who want to help you.

Comment: sorry everyone actually I'm new to stack .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**just replace the condition of the there loops with 26. Now the exception index out of bound will not occur**

public class SuggestingAppNames {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("the possible outcomes are");

```
String a = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
String d[] = a.split(",");

String b = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
String e[] = b.split(",");

String c = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
String f[] = c.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < 26 ; i++) {

  for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {

    for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++) {

      System.out.println(d[i] + e[j] + f[k]);

    }
  }

}
```

}
}